# How to make a square rotate in a Windows Program?

Tags: c++, windows

I drew a square to the screen using Rectangle(), and I want to make that square rotate clockwise by 1 degree every time the 'r' key is pressed.

I know how to set up the pressing of 'r', but I have no clue where to even begin with making the rotation happen. Any ideas?

It is Win32 Project. Im still new to this windows programming so its nothing fancy. All Iv done is made a Win32 Project, made the blank empty window, and drew a square with Rectangle( ).

Comment: There is a lot more details that are left out in this question. For example, what input do you want to use (if there is a preference for Win32 or the old DX8). What is your api for drawing? GDI+, DirectX, etc.

Comment: Some more details about your environment would help.  Is this MFC/WinForms/WPF?

Comment: It is Win32 Project. Im still new to this windows programming so its nothing fancy.  All Iv done is made a Win32 Project, made the blank empty window, and drew a square with Rectangle( ).

Comment: If you are just starting, you shouldn't start with obsolete technologies like GDI. Try using modern technologies like WPF and Direct2D instead.

Comment: Well its for a project, so I kind of have to do it this way. Forgot to add the homework tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of methods. Microsoft generally wants you to draw using Direct2D, so you may consider looking into that. For Direct2D, there are two examples in the MSDN Library:

- [Draw Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371016.aspx)
- [How to Rotate an Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756687.aspx) (this example shows how to draw a rotated square!)

With GDI, you can either use [`Polygon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162814.aspx) and calculate the coordinates with sine and cosine, or apply a linear transformation with [`SetWorldTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145104.aspx).